# How do I visualise this graph and answer the question?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

This is the question I have:

Consider the graph defined as follows:

Vertices: Pow({a,b,c})
Edges: {X,Y} is an edge if it
is not the case that (X⊆Y or Y⊆X)

Which of the following properties does this graph have?

- Eulerian path
- Hamiltonian path
- Bipartite
- Connected
- Chromatic number 3
- Planar
- None of these

I am having trouble visualising the graph from the given information. I came up with the following in my attempt:

Vertices:- a,b,c,ab,bc,ca,abc,∅
Edges :- (a,b),(a,c),(b,c),(a,bc),(b,ca),(c,ab)

This is how I drew it in my notebook:

[image]

From these, I thought the only property the graph satisfies from the given list is 'planar'. Either that, or 'None of these'.

But I have a strong feeling that I haven't got the graph right. Please help.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: To expand on Misha’s comment, the graph has only $8$ vertices, so it’s really not hard to draw the graph.

Comment: I had already drawn it in my notebook, but didn't know how to draw it digitally here. So I updated the question to add the hand drawn picture.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%3E2%2C+2-%3E3%2C+3-%3E1%2C+3-%3E4%2C+4-%3E1&lk=3

Comment: You are missing edges between pairs of 2-element subsets.

Comment: But the question says {X,Y} is an edge if it is not the case that (X⊆Y or Y⊆X).
Doesn't this mean that whenever a vertex is a subset of any other vertex, there can't be an edge between them? I could be wrong with how I have understood this. I probably am.

Comment: Jeez, I get it now! How stupid of me!